# Are they interchangeable, "it's not the time to watch the match" and "the match hasn't started yet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The match starts at 5 pm and you turned your TV on at 4:45 pm.

And you said "**it's not the time to watch the match**" (the same way you say "**it's not time to have dinner**") or "**the match hasn't started yet**".

**Are they interchangeable?**

Comment: Well, obviously you can only watch the match once it has started, so I think most people would say "It's not time _for the match_ yet."

Answer (score 0):

They're obviously not fully interchangeable - it's possible that it's not the time to watch the match because the match has already *finished*.

Overall, you could use "it's not the time to..." in a literal fashion to mean that something cannot be done at this time, but to me it wouldn't sound natural. Usually, this phrase means that you *shouldn't* be doing something, rather than that you *aren't able to* - because it's inappropriate, for example, or because it'll make things worse.

For instance, if someone has just died and your friend wants to watch a match, you could tell him that "it's not the time to watch a match" - meaning that it's inappropriate to do so when you're grieving.